# не срабатывает setTimeout

Tags: jquery

На форме таблица. В таблице есть `input` "Цена" и "Мин. цена". при отправке формы происходит проверка этих полей. Нужно чтобы цена была не меньше минимальной цены. Если поле "Цена" меньше, то `input` присваивается класс `.check`. Дальше я хочу сделать подсветку всех `input class='check'`. и через 5 сек чтобы подсветка исчезла. 
мой jquery:

```
function lightFields(){
    $('#t_sale_order').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.check').css({'border-color':'#d8512d'});

        setTimeout(function(){
            $(this).find('.check').removeAttr('style').removeClass('check');
        }, 5000);

    });
}
```

Подсветка выполняется, не выполняется удаление стилей через 5 сек. Может я неправильно использую setTimeout?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос еще `html` разметку и покажите момент, когда вы вызываете `lightFields()`

Comment: @Kley Зачем удалять класс, у вас получается код одноразовый. второй раз класса уже не будет. Может стоит ставить элементам рамку и по таймауту перекрашивать рамку в обычный ее цвет, не трогая классы и style целиком

Comment: _this_ внутри setTimeout - это не тот же _this_ что снаружи

Comment: @Grundy, вот я это подозревала. а как теперь добраться до того, что снаружи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как `this` внутри `setTimeout` указывает не на html элемент, его нельзя использовать так же как внутри функции `each`, но его можно сохранить.

```
$('#t_sale_order').each(function(){
    var elementsCheck = $(this).find('.check').css({'border-color':'#d8512d'});

    setTimeout(function(){
        elementsCheck.removeAttr('style').removeClass('check');
    }, 5000);

});
```

Comment: Эх, а я `html` просил. хотел еще более оптимально сделать, чем удаление атрибута `style` и прочей чепухни)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну основным тут все равно был неправильный this, все остальное не особо и важно наверное:)